# In Excel get percentage of values in each histogram bucket

Tags: excel, histogram, bucket

Can we show histogram data labels by percentage instead of absolute numbers of frequencies in Excel. I.e. I want to know what percentage of numbers is in which bucket.

[image]

Comment: I am pretty sure you can't. You need to build a table of frequencies then use it in the chart. About your image, note that you need to right click on the data label and not on the bars to edit those labels.

Comment: Got the same question - can't believe there isn't a built in function for this.